# pagetotal for articles - Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I would like to know how to cite an article indicating the total number of pages in the article. I added the field `pagetotal` to the `.bib` file and added the following code in my Preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{pagetotal}{\mkpagetotal[bookpagination]{#1~pp.}}
```

However, both with and without this code, or its variants with `Pagetotal` instead of `pagetotal` all fail. Understnadably, the key `bookpagination` may affect only the way this field is formatted for books. So, any pointer in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Please add a MWE (minimal working example) for get more information and then can help you.

Answer (score 6):

The default `biblatex` styles as implemented by `standard.bbx` only print the `pagetotal` field for book-like entry types such as `@book`, `@collection`, `@booklet`, `@thesis` etc.
Naturally, `@article` is not among those types, so by default the `pagetotal` is ignored there.
Considering the fact that articles normally come with a `pages` field indicating the first and last page of the journal they can be found in, the `pagetotal` field does seem indeed superfluous, since (in general) its informational value can be obtained by a small computation on the `pages` field (some online journal do not have pages as such, in those cases it might be useful).

In order to include the `pagetotal` in the output - despite its redundancy, we have to include the command `\printfield{pagetotal}%` in the driver for `@article`. To do this we hook into the macro `note+pages` which is only used by `@article`

```
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}% this ...
  \printfield{pagetotal}% ... and this is new
  \newunit}
```

We also make sure the field is properly formatted (as the standard `bookpagination` will not help here)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pagetotal}{\mkpagetotal[pagination]{#1}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{BarPalNumEst,
  author    = {Hilary C. Barth and Annie M. Paladino},
  title     = {The development of numerical estimation},
  subtitle  = {Evidence against a representational shift},
  journal   = {Developmental Science},
  volume    = {14},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {125-135},
  date      = {2011-01},
  doi       = {10.1111/j.1467-7687.2010.00962.x},
  gender    = {pf},
  pagetotal = {11},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pagetotal}{\mkpagetotal[pagination]{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This modification can be done for the other entry types currently lacking `pagetotal` as well. For `@inbook`, `@incollection` and friends, the modification could be done to `chapter+pages`.
But here this modification seems especially unnecessary, since these entries should all contain proper physical page numbers in their `pages` field.

```
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit}
```

Comment: Thx! As of today, I get different line breaks: https://i.imgur.com/38eS4A1.png . Is it possible to alter `note+pages` via a patch command (such that if the contents of the default `note+pages` ever changes in `biblatex`, nothing is done)?

Comment: @AlbertNash You can use `xpatch` and put the entire current macro definition in the search arg. Of course that won't help if the macro definition is extended at the beginning or the end, but it'd be a start. In theory I can imagine comparing the macro definition to a hard-coded version in your document, but I don't know if I would go through all that trouble for a fairly small change. Plus it won't help you if changes relevant to the output are made outside of the `notes+pages` macro.