# Articleno in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

Does biblatex have an `articleno` field or equivalent? In addition, can I use article number in page ranges?
The problematic article in questions has the following:

```
pages = {19:1--19:39},
articleno = {19},
```

and can be found here: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2431218

Comment: You could perhaps use the `note` field.

Comment: As of now, http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2431218 is redirected to https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2431211.2431218, and this DOESN'T show `pages = {19:1--19:39}, articleno = {19}` when clicking on he citation button. Instead, we see `articleno = {19}, numpages = {39}`.

Answer (score 11):

**Updated answer**

The  field for these sort of jobs in the `biblatex` standard data model is called `eid`. (Up to and including version 3.14 of `biblatex` the field is only available for `@article`s, but from v3.15 onwards it will be supported by all types where it makes sense, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/1000).

If you don't like the default output, you can modify it to show "Art. No.".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{artno}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{artno = {Art\adddotspace No\adddot}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{eid}{\bibstring{artno}\addabbrvspace #1}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{mooney,
  author    = {Mooney, Carl H. and Roddick, John F.},
  title     = {Sequential Pattern Mining -- Approaches and Algorithms},
  journal   = {ACM Comput. Surv.},
  volume    = {45},
  number    = {2},
  date      = {2013-03},
  pages     = {19:1--19:39},
  eid       = {19},
  pagetotal = {39},
  doi       = {10.1145/2431211.2431218},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{mooney}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

**Old answer**

If for some reason you don't want to use `eid` you can define a new `articleno` field.
This is done in a separate `.dbx` file called `articleno.dbx` (in the MWE it is created via `filecontents`)

```
\ProvidesFile{articleno.dbx}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=integer]{articleno}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[article]{articleno}
```

We can also define a new bibstring to be printed before the article number

```
\NewBibliographyString{artno}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{artno = {Art\adddotspace No\adddot}}
```

The `articleno` field is introduced by this new string

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{articleno}{\bibstring{artno}\addabbrvspace #1}
```

We then redefine the `note+pages` macro to also print the `articleno` field

```
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{articleno}
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,datamodel=articleno]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{mooney,
  author    = {Mooney, Carl H. and Roddick, John F.},
  title     = {Sequential Pattern Mining -- Approaches and Algorithms},
  journal   = {ACM Comput. Surv.},
  volume    = {45},
  number    = {2},
  date      = {2013-03},
  pages     = {19:1--19:39},
  articleno = {19},
  pagetotal = {39},
  doi       = {10.1145/2431211.2431218},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{articleno.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{articleno.dbx}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=integer]{articleno}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[article]{articleno}
\end{filecontents*}

\NewBibliographyString{artno}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{artno = {Art\adddotspace No\adddot}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{articleno}{\bibstring{artno}\addabbrvspace #1}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{articleno}
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{mooney}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do the same for an `@inproceedings` bib entry. There above MWE doesn't work. I'm suspecting it's due to `note+pages`. Do you have any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: @m8mble For `@inproceedings` you want to modify `chapter+pages` instead of `note+pages`. If that does not help you, please consider asking a new question.

Comment: Works like a charm. Highly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any way to do this using bibtex as a backend instead of biber? Biber is causing a lot of problems with incorrect first/last name detection for me, so I had to switch to bibtex, but I also have citations with articleno...

Comment: @RalfJung There is no officially supported way to extend the standard data model with arbitrary field with BibTeX as backend. But actually, there already is a field like `articleno`, it is called `eid`. So maybe that helps you (see the edit). In any case I recommend you look into getting Biber to work for you. For most use cases it should be painless to switch from BibTeX to Biber. If you want to ask a question about your Biber troubles, I will be happy to look at it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into eid, but I doubt texlive has a new enough biblatex (how do I see the version number?). However, the publisher is using "articleno" so I'd have to edit their BibTeX, see for example [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3158154). As for Biber, I'll try to minimize but the behavior was *really strange* and it took me hours to even figure out what was going on. I'll make a Biber bugreport and ping you.

Comment: @RalfJung For `@article`s `eid` has been around for a long time. The pull request I linked will just make it available for more entry types in the next version of `biblatex` (which isn't released yet).

Comment: As of now, https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2431211.2431218 doesn't have `pages = {19:1--19:39}, articleno = {19}`. I see `articleno = {19}, numpages = {39}` instead. Does it change your answer?

Comment: Moreover, the value of the `pagetotal` field doesn't show up. Write `pagetotal = {100}` instead of `pagetotal = {39}` and observe that 100 doesn't show up in the PDF produced.

Comment: @AlbertNash No, I don't think this change in ACM `.bib` export changes anything relevant for the answer. If you need `pagetotal`, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151752/35864.