# Biblatex removes ~ (no break space)

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, biber

Somewhere between biblatex v3.0 and v3.7, biblatex (or perhaps the biber back-end) has started to remove `~` characters (i.e. non-breaking spaces) from certain fields (notably `pages`) in my bibliography entries.

For instance, the field `Pages={article~1}`, as it appears in my `.bib` file, gets turned into `\field{pages}{article 1}` in the resulting `.bbl` file (notice how the `~`is gone), and because this turns up at the and of a line there is a line break between "article" and "1" in the final `.pdf`.

Does anyone know how I can keep this from happening?

Comment: Why do you use the `pages` field to store information other than page numbers or page ranges?

Comment: I assume the `pages` field is parsed by Biber to allow for detection of all kinds of range indicators and such. You should probably not abuse it in such a way. There are other ways to store additional information.

Comment: @PaulGaborit & @moewe I guess you are both right. But this kind of "abuse" is fairly common in many bibtex exporting websites. I think the reason is more and more conference proceedings exist only digitally and editors don't bother numbering pages in favour of numbering the contained articles. I guess I could use an `articleno` field instead. But Biblatex doesn't seem to natively support that.

Comment: It turns out @moewe already provided a solution for `articleno` support in Biblatex [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194931/3800). I'll go and try that now.

Comment: It works. So then I guess this question can be closed. Although it may still be useful for other to know that the removing of `~` is something older Biblatex versions didn't do.

Comment: It still is bad form to abuse the field in such a way even if the export tools of some web services tend to do such a thing (sometimes they do even more horrid things, I find that often manual adjustments are necessary to get proper output). Can you verify that older version of Biber didn't do such a thing and if so which versions? (I'd have thought that Biber has been doing parsing of the `pages` field for a really long time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pages` is a range field, the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) says

> Range fields consist of one or more ranges where all dashes are normalized and replaced by the command `\bibrangedash`. A range is something optionally followed by one or more dashes optionally followed by some non-dash (e.g. `5--7`). Any number of consecutive dashes will only yield a single range dash. A typical example of a range field is the pages field.

So Biber has to actively parse the `pages` field. In the process of parsing it the `~` is removed.

```
Pages={article~1}
```

Is a malformed `pages` field anyway. I suspect you are looking for the `eid` field.

Of course you can start a feature request https://github.com/plk/biber/issues and ask Biber not to normalise the `pages` field.