# How to properly convert an article with articleno+numpages of ACM into the syntax understood by biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, biber

Continuing [Articleno in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194355/articleno-in-biblatex), let us consider the bibtex citation taken from https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3492545 (click on the big symbol ”):

```
@article{10.1145/3492545,
author = {Lamport, Leslie and Merz, Stephan},
title = {Prophecy Made Simple},
year = {2022},
issue_date = {June 2022},
publisher = {Association for Computing Machinery},
address = {New York, NY, USA},
volume = {44},
number = {2},
issn = {0164-0925},
url = {https://doi.org/10.1145/3492545},
doi = {10.1145/3492545},
abstract = {Prophecy variables were introduced in the article “The Existence of Refinement Mappings” by Abadi and Lamport. They were difficult to use in practice. We describe a new kind of prophecy variable that we find much easier to use. We also reformulate ideas from that article in a more mathematical way.},
journal = {ACM Trans. Program. Lang. Syst.},
month = {apr},
articleno = {6},
numpages = {27},
keywords = {auxiliary variable, state machine, Formal specification, refinement}
}
```

The fields `articleno` and `numpages` are unknown to bib(la)tex.  What's the best approximation of `articleno={6}, numpages = {27}` in the article type of biblatex?  For starters, DBLP makes it [simple for `bibtex`](https://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/journals/toplas/LamportM22.html?view=bibtex):

```
@article{DBLP:journals/toplas/LamportM22,
  author    = {Leslie Lamport and
               Stephan Merz},
  title     = {Prophecy Made Simple},
  journal   = {{ACM} Trans. Program. Lang. Syst.},
  volume    = {44},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {6:1--6:27},
  year      = {2022},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1145/3492545},
  doi       = {10.1145/3492545},
  timestamp = {Thu, 25 Aug 2022 08:37:12 +0200},
  biburl    = {https://dblp.org/rec/journals/toplas/LamportM22.bib},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, https://dblp.org}
}
```

The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194931 mentions the fields `eid` and `pagetotal`, but unfortunately, `pagetotal` is ignored for the type `@article`.

Comment: The question you linked received a clear answer about `articleno`, and different ways to handle the case. A question which you just repeat here, I don't really understand where you are trying to get. (You say here "mentions `eid`", that seems unfair to the thorough answer there). And, indeed it seems the clear `biblatex`'s equivalent to `numpages` is `pagetotal`, as you say yourself, whether the `article` type uses it or not is up to the style you choose or, failing that, to your configurations.

Comment: @gusbrs According to the documentation of biblatex, `@article` does not have the field `pagetotal` at all, regardless of the style. The linked answer missed this fact, probably because the input was misleading, providing the same information "19" twice, orelse biblatex has changed in this respect since the answer updated last. As for “your configurations”, I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: The field `pagetotal` exists for `biblatex` as it is declared in the data model, the list you probably looked at to say "`@article` does not have the field `pagetotal` at all, regardless of the style" lists the fields used by the standard styles. If you look at the top of the list, it is introduced by "Note that the
mapping of fields to an entry type is ultimately at the discretion of the bibliography
style. The lists below therefore serve two purposes. They indicate the fields supported
by the standard styles which come with this package and they also serve as a model
for custom styles."

Comment: ... And by "your configurations" I mean it is always possible to tweak the style to make it use the field, for which there are many examples on the site. And the answer you mention is one such example. But, anyway, that's not what you are asking.

Comment: @gusbrs No, the linked answer only says how to introduce a NEW field (namely, `articleno`). It doesn't say how to add an ALREADY EXISTING field (such as `pagetotal`). Without additional knowledge, this may require anywhere between a one-liner and a full page of code for all circumstances (say, different languages).

Comment: It does that too... But, anyway, to me this just looks like a duplicate, but I won't pester you further about it.

Comment: @gusbrs Besides `articleno`, the linked answer only says something about `pages`, which is both *already existing* AND *declared for `@article`*. It would be guessing from our side on whether `pagetotal` could be added in the same or similar (how exactly?) way.