# Getting the field 'pagetotal' to show in @inproceedings (biblatex)?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151752/2634), the OP asks how to get the field `pagetotal` to appear in articles using biblatex, but I want to get the same field to show in `@inproceedings` entries as well, but I can't get that working. Based on [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151761/2634) to the linked question, here's what I've tried so far (which doesn't work):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{BarPalNumEst,
  author    = {Hilary C. Barth and Annie M. Paladino},
  title     = {The development of numerical estimation},
  subtitle  = {Evidence against a representational shift},
  journal   = {Developmental Science},
  volume    = {14},
  number    = {1},
  date      = {2011-01},
  doi       = {10.1111/j.1467-7687.2010.00962.x},
  gender    = {pf},
  pagetotal = {11},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{pagetotal}{\mkpagetotal[pagination]{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `inproceedings` the relevant macro is `chapter+pages` not `note+pages`.  You need to look in `standard.bbx` to discover this.  With this change the solution works.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{BarPalNumEst,
  author    = {Hilary C. Barth and Annie M. Paladino},
  title     = {The development of numerical estimation},
  subtitle  = {Evidence against a representational shift},
  journal   = {Developmental Science},
  volume    = {14},
  number    = {1},
  date      = {2011-01},
  doi       = {10.1111/j.1467-7687.2010.00962.x},
  gender    = {pf},
  pagetotal = {11},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{pagetotal}{\mkpagetotal[bookpagination]{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```