# Displaying pagetotal

Tags: biblatex

How do I convince `biblatex-chicago` to display the total pages of a book? The required field seems to be `pagetotal`, which can be disabled as an option, but even if I explicitly enable it, it is ignored.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book { iwamoto1937,
editor = {Yutaka Iwamoto},
year = {1937},
title = {Mahāsāhasrapramardanī (Pañcarakṣā I)}, 
series = {Beiträge zur Indologie},
number = {1},
pagetotal = {43},
location = {Kyoto},
options = {bookpages=true},
}

\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I would use `pages={43 pages}`. I have never seen a `pagetotal` field in BibTeX...it is certainly not in any bst file that I use.

Comment: @Andrew It';s a standard `biblatex` field, but `biblatex-chicago` does rather have it's own ideas about things

Comment: Looking at the docs for `biblatex-chicago` it seems it does not support the field at all

Comment: @JosephWright I do see `pagetotal` mentioned in the `biblatex-chicago` docs, followed by a reference to 4.4.2. But indeed if there I read about `bookpages=true` I understand it is about the `pages` field, which @Andrew suggested to use, not `pagetotal`. Now Andrew's suggestion sort of works actually, but normally the `pages` field was intended for the page range of an article within a journal or similar cases.

Comment: @muk.li Yes but not in the bit that defines what fields are recognised! More importantly, it's not in the code at all, and since `biblatex-chicago` seems to do most things from scratch that means no inheritance from the `biblatex` core styles.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the correction Joseph. I'm not a biblatex convert and so am showing my ignorance...sorry!

Comment: See also [pagetotal for articles - Biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151752/35864) [Getting the field 'pagetotal' to show in @inproceedings (biblatex)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208769/35864), though for `biblatex-chicago` the redefinitions might need to be tweaked a bit, I will investigate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `biblatex-chicago` ignores the `pagetotal` field.

So we will have to enable it ourselves, we add this support to the `pubstate` macro (this macro is used in all drivers, as far as I can see and its position is fairly fitting, I think)

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{pubstate}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@reprint}%
  {\iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
    {\iffieldundef{year}% Fix for consistency???
      {}%
      {\printtext{% 16th ed.
          \usebibmacro{choosepubstring}%
          \printdate\addperiod}\nopunct}}
    {\iffieldundef{origyear}%
      {}%
      {\printtext{% 16th ed.
          \usebibmacro{choosepubstring}%
          \printorigdate\addperiod}\nopunct}}}%
  {\printfield{pubstate}}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}}
\makeatother
```

We just added `\printfield{pagetotal}` to the standard definition of `chicago-authordate.bbx`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book {iwamoto1937,
editor = {Yutaka Iwamoto},
year = {1937},
title = {A Non-Unicode Title}, 
series = {Just ASCII Here},
number = {1},
pagetotal = {43},
location = {Kyoto},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{pubstate}{% changed to \renewbibmacro to get rid of the warning.
  \iftoggle{cms@reprint}%
  {\iftoggle{cms@switchdates}%
    {\iffieldundef{year}% Fix for consistency???
      {}%
      {\printtext{% 16th ed.
          \usebibmacro{choosepubstring}%
          \printdate\addperiod}\nopunct}}
    {\iffieldundef{origyear}%
      {}%
      {\printtext{% 16th ed.
          \usebibmacro{choosepubstring}%
          \printorigdate\addperiod}\nopunct}}}%
  {\printfield{pubstate}}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]