# Modifications Bibliography - pagetotal and abbreviations

Tags: biblatex, biber

At present I am working on my bibliography. I have two issues which I am not able to fix: - I want to insert the pagetotal in my bibliography. - Instead of the institution`s only its abbreviation should appear.

```
  \documentclass{scrbook}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
    \usepackage[english,german,ngerman]{babel}                                          
    \usepackage{lmodern}                                                                
    \usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
    \usepackage[language=autobib,backend=biber,citetracker=true,autolang=other,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,uniquename=false,uniquelist=true,isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex}
    \AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}

    \renewcommand*{\revsdnamedelim}{} 
    \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash} 
    \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

    \renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space} 
    \renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\multilistdelim} 


    % --- () footnotes
    % --- () year footnotes
    \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

    \newbibmacro*{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}{%
      \iffieldundef{labelyear}
        {}
        {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
           \printfield{labelyear}%
           \printfield{extrayear}}}}

    \renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
      \iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
           {\printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
         \usebibmacro{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}


    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

    \AtBeginBibliography{%
      \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}}



    %%%%%%%%%% MODIFICATION: BIBLIOGRAPY %%%%%%%%%%

    % --- Sort authors --- % 
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

    % --- colon after author and year --- % 
    \renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} 

    % --- No "-" for the same authors --- % 
    \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{dashed=false}        


    % --- more space between references --- % 
    \setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip} 


    % - German / English literature - %
        \DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{%
        \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Jg\adddot\addcomma}%
        \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addspace Nr\adddot\addnbspace#1}% 
        \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Aufl\adddot\addcomma}%
        }

        \DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
        \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol\adddot\addnbspace #1\addcomma}%
        \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addspace No\adddot\addnbspace#1}%
        \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Ed\adddot\addcomma}%
        }


    % title without quotation marks %
        \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} 
        \DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1}
        \DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1}
        \DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1}

    % No publisher %
        \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
        \printlist{location}%
        \iflistundef{publisher}
        {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
        {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
        %\printlist{publisher}%
        \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{date}%
        \newunit}

    % URL %
        \urlstyle{same}
        %\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\printtext{URL\addcolon}\space\url{#1}}       % "URL" --> "Unter:"
        %\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}               % date without brackets
        %\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%                                   % "besucht am" --> "am"
        %urlseen = {besucht am}}
        %\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%                                   % "besucht am" --> "am"
        %urlseen = {accessed}}


    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}


    @misc{PRA.2013,
     year = {2013},
     title = {The Prudential Regulation Authority’s approach to banking supervision},
     url = {www.bankofengland.co.uk/publications/Documents/praapproach/bankingappr1304.pdf},
     urldate = {2017-01-31},
     number = {3},
     series = {PRA approach documents},
     editor = {{Prudential Regulation Authority}},
     shortauthor = {PRA},
     pagetotal = {42},
     hyphenation = {english}
    }

    @misc{PRA.2013b,
     year = {2013},
     title = {The Prudential Regulation Authority’s approach to banking supervision},
     url = {www.bankofengland.co.uk/publications/Documents/praapproach/bankingappr1304.pdf},
     urldate = {2017-01-31},
     number = {3},
     series = {PRA approach documents},
     editor = {{Prudential Regulation Authority}},
     shortauthor = {PRA},
     pagetotal = {42},
     hyphenation = {german}
    }

    \end{filecontents*}
    \bibliography{\jobname}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
      \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{\stripzeros{#1}\adddot}%
      \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
      \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
      \protected\def\mkbibneutord{\mkbibordinal}%
      \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
        \iffieldundef{#3}
          {}
          {\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
           \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
        \iffieldundef{#2}
          {}
          {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
           \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
        \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
      \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
        \iffieldundef{#3}
          {}
          {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot
           \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\thinspace}}%
        \iffieldundef{#2}
          {}
          {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#2}}%
           \iffieldundef{#1}
             {}
             {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot\thinspace}}}%
              \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
    }

    \begin{document}

    \noindent
    \textcites[][]{PRA.2013}{PRA.2013b}
    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not use comments to expand your question, but edit your question instead.

Comment: We can't compile without the bib entries you cite. And the thing about the institution might make sense if we had them, I can't tell.

Comment: @TeXnician. Sorry. Yesterday I was not able to insert the code an my question - I don`t know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `pagetotal` is not printed for all entry types. By default we get it for `@book`, `@collection` and similar types, where it makes sense. Other types such as `@article` and `@incollection`, which normally have a `pages` field don't get `pagetotal`. We can add that field for `@misc` with

```
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifentrytype{misc}{\printfield{pagetotal}}{}}
```

See also [pagetotal for articles - Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151752/35864)

If you only ever want to see 'PRA' instead of `Prudential Regulation Authority`, why don't you give it as `editor` directly

```
editor = {PRA},
```

It makes no sense to keep `{{Prudential Regulation Authority}}` if you don't plan to use it.

Comment: Thank you, moewe.  It works fine. Is it possible to get "pages" or "Seiten" as output after the pagetotal? It is true, that it doesn`t make sense to put the full name into the editor field, but(!) if I need it later I have to change all entries like that in the *.bib. At first I thought it would be a good idea to have a reference like "Prudential Regulation Authority (PRA), ed. (2013): ...." but it looks a little bit strange to me especially when brackets follow brackets.

Comment: @TRJW With the standard settings I get '42 S.' is that enough for you? Or do you require 'Seiten'? That would be harder as you probably want 'S. 12-24' when citing and not 'Seiten 12-24' and they both come from the same bibstring.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see this modification will change several other settings. I think it looks fine right now. :)